# React Native How to convert fetch to axios?

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, fetch-api

I'm trying to change my project from using fetch to axios. When I tried to change it, I wasn't able to make it work just like it should be when I used fetch. I got this error : response.json is not a function. (In 'response.json()', 'response.json' is undefined)

Using Fetch:

```
        fetch(URLs._dashboard, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "Accept": "application/json",
            'Authorization': myToken,
        },
        signal: abortCont.signal,
        }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then(async (result) => {
            setApiData(result); 
            AsyncStorage.setItem('@code', result.code);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            if(error.name === 'AbortError'){
                console.log('fetch aborted');
            } 
        });
```

Using Axios

```
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: URLs._dashboard,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "Accept": "application/json",
            'Authorization': myToken,
        }, 
        signal: abortCont.signal,
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then(async (result) => { 
            setApiData(result); 
            AsyncStorage.setItem('@code', result.code);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        if(error.name === 'AbortError'){
            console.log('fetch aborted');
        }  
    });
```

Comment: So what, specifically, is the problem? What have you done to debug this? I would expect a nice, big, obvious error in the Console and `json()` not being a function which should lead you to the Axios documentation to see what you should use instead.

Comment: @Quentin I got this error response.json is not a function. (In 'response.json()', 'response.json' is undefined)

Comment: OK, so now you've got to the point two thirds through my previous comment. Now follow through with the rest of the comment.

Comment: @Quentin it doesnt say anything else. It only said that

Comment: My comment also said: "which should lead you to the Axios documentation to see what you should use instead".

Comment: `axios` doesn't have `json` method. Libraries use different APIs and you have to read the documentation to know how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to parse or transform the response using .json() because the axios response its already json formatted. The response you get its `data` which is going to have:

```
{
  // `data` is the response that was provided by the server
  data: {},

  // `status` is the HTTP status code from the server response
  status: 200,

  // `statusText` is the HTTP status message from the server response
  // As of HTTP/2 status text is blank or unsupported.
  // (HTTP/2 RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.4)
  statusText: 'OK',

  // `headers` the HTTP headers that the server responded with
  // All header names are lower cased and can be accessed using the bracket notation.
  // Example: `response.headers['content-type']`
  headers: {},

  // `config` is the config that was provided to `axios` for the request
  config: {},

  // `request` is the request that generated this response
  // It is the last ClientRequest instance in node.js (in redirects)
  // and an XMLHttpRequest instance in the browser
  request: {}
}
```

All this you can find in the axios docs which you should be reading if you want to use it. So make sure you create the habit of reading the docs if you want to succeed.

More of axios [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro).